# Quemar etiqueta [column]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

Actualmente hay unas 26 preguntas etiquetadas [column](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/column).

En mi opinión, esta es una meta-etiqueta, según está definido en el [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Sobra decir que no hay un wiki de etiqueta que oriente sobre su uso y que, en mi opinión, la etiqueta no hace ningún sentido y no ha quien pueda considerarse experto en ella.

Las preguntas que actualmente tienen esa etiqueta van de temas tan variados, como columnas de sentencias [sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), columnas en DataFrames de [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), columnas en DataTables de [jquery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), columnas en tablas [html](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), en [r](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) y más.

De acuerdo a experiencias previas, si esta pregunta recibe 8 votos positivos *al hilo*, yo mismo eliminaré las preguntas para que la etiqueta desaparezca. Si recibe votos negativos, pero alcanza una diferencia de +10, haré lo mismo.

Comment: Esto te lo digo por las dudas. Recordaste borrar las preguntas que se ocultan debido a tus preferencias de etiquetas que no quieres ver?

Comment: jajaja, gracias @Dante, es una lección que aprendí desde la primera vez, así que me he asegurado de ello.

Comment: De ahí debe ser que recuerdo que le pasó a alguien. Bien que te aseguraste!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo mencionado en la pregunta, al alcanzar el soporte de la comunidad, he realizado yo mismo la edición de las preguntas para quemar la etiqueta, que debiera desaparecer automáticamente luego de unos días.